# input a character into an enum variable using scanf in c

Tags: c, enums, scanf

Hi guys i need to write an Program for univerity that organises a queue using an enum but im having a lot of Problems with the enum.

```
int main() {

enum priority {
    L , l, n, h, H      //Todo: Priority enum Lowest = 0 Highest = 4
};

char option = 'X';
printf("Priority: ");
scanf(" %c", &option);
enum priority priorityvar = option;
printf("%d", priorityvar);
```

The Problem is that when i'm scanning the char that the variable priorityvar is always set to the literal charcater and there isnt being recognized by the enum, and i cant read it directly into the variable because the compiler gives me warnings saying i cannot adress a variable of type enum with a %d or %c. Anybody have any idea how to solve this? I feel like this could have been solved easier without an enum but i have to use an enum to solve the task for uni

Comment: You are setting the variable priorityvar nowhere after its initialization. Just assign the variable option to the variable priorityvar. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the variable is then set to the character c and when i print out priorityvar it gives me the ascii code of the letter instead of the enum number

Comment: Also you need to assign an integer 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 instead of a character.

Comment: If you had named `L` as, say `LOWPRIORITY` then the situation becomes more obvious. And the name isn't even present in the runtime code (except perhaps for a debugger).

Comment: `switch (option){ case 'L': priorityvar=0; break; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right answer:

```
*#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv)// Don't worry on the arguments.
{
enum priority {
    L , l, n, h, H     // Todo: Priority enum Lowest =
                       // 0 Highest = 4
}priorityvar;
char x, option;
printf("Priority: ");
scanf(" %c", &x);
option=x;
priorityvar = option;
printf("%c", priorityvar);
return 0;
}
```

It was ran in Code:Blocks ver 16.1 on debian 9.13 on Xfce 4.12

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert char representing the digit to its integer value.

```
enum priority priorityvar;
if(isdigit((unsigned char)option && option >= '0' && option < '5') priorityvar = option - '0';
else { /* wrong input - handle error*/ }
```

or if you want letter representing the priority:

```
switch(option)
{
    case 'L':
        priorityvar = L;
        break;
    case 'l':
        priorityvar = l;
        break;
    case 'n':
        priorityvar = n;
        break;
    case 'h':
        priorityvar = h;
        break;
    case 'H':
        priorityvar = H;
        break;
    default:
        /* handle error */
        break;
}
```